# Transparent Request Forwarding (No HTTP Redirect)

Tags: php, symfony

I have a requirement that should present terms and conditions to the user for each new session.

I wrote a `Listener` that will listen `GetResponseEvent` and it is declared as follows:

```
class: MyProject\CoreBundle\TermsAndConditionsDispatcherListener
arguments: ["@logger"]
tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

And I basically perform the process following this logic:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
        return;
    }
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if ($request->getSession()->get("contractAccepted")) {
        return;
    }
    if ($request->getPathInfo() == "/terms/accepted") {
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($request->getSession()->get("firstRequestUrl")));
    }
    $request->getSession()->set("firstRequestUrl", $request->getUri());
    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse("/terms"));        
}
```

But as you can see, it performs two redirects, the first one to redirect the user to `/terms` and the second to the original requested url when he accepts the terms and conditions.

Is there a way to modify this process in order to avoid redirections?

I thought something like: on first request I store the original `Request` object on session and build another to be processed in order to show the terms and when user confirms the terms and conditions a certain url is invoked like `/terms/accepted`, at that point the original request would be loaded from sesssion and processed.

Is the process above described possible? How would my code look like?